# Why does Kai resent the Tengu?

Tags: 47-ronin

In *47 Ronin*, why does Kai resent the Tengu?  They seem to have taught him so much, and they help him and the Ronin by giving them swords.

Comment: I'm no expert on Japanese culture but I think it would be something like doing a deal with the devil - you go in eyes open and wary. At least in this case due to his past experiences they represent the devil he knows.